# Why My Image not aligning to the right?

Tags: css, wordpress

in this wordpress page, I align my image to the right. but it always shows in the left. how do I solve it?
http://lionsfatherdaughterdance.com/faq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use float:right to the image tag i.e.

Try below `CSS`

```
.alignright
{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I forgot to add that in my style sheet.

Comment: Take a look at all [WordPress’ generated classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS). Also consider marking this answer as correct.

Comment: @user2802110 : you might want to accept the answer if it helped!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Add to your `style.css`:

```
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
```